# Tensorflow Extended (TFX): Is there an easy way to debug functions from Transorm component?

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, tensorflow2.0, tfx, tensorflow-transform

I am supposed to modify a function which is a part of [Transorm component](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/transform). It is a long series of tensorflow operations and I am not sure a. how particular steps affect processed variables b. what does my input look like. I can't just run them in eager mode because most of them are graph-mode-only. Does anyone know an easy way to see effects of particular lines?

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census#put_it_all_together_2). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably by writing a unittest using tft_unit:
https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/0b55b89da3f2e737a8d4847a060d644181ddce9c/tensorflow_transform/beam/tft_unit.py#L85

This way you can feed test data, add prints if needed, and iteratively make changes to the preprocessing_fn.